# Wavedata and openal not working

Tags: java, lwjgl, openal

I am trying to use `openal` to play sound in my game.

But when I try to buffer the data with:

```
AL10.alBufferData(buffer, waveFile.format, waveFile.data,
                waveFile.samplerate);
```

It gives the Error : `AL_INVALID_ENUM`

I realy dont understand this becouse I am doing what all the tutorials do.
Please help me.

Here is the code for the sound class that stores the buffer data

```
public Sound(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int error;
    // Load wav data into a buffer.
    buffer = AL10.alGenBuffers();

    error = AL10.alGetError();
    if (error != AL10.AL_NO_ERROR) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + Maths.getALErrorString(error));
    }
    InputStream fin = null;

    File f = new File(path);
    fin = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsoluteFile());

    error = AL10.alGetError();
    if (error != AL10.AL_NO_ERROR) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + Maths.getALErrorString(error));
    }

    WaveData waveFile = WaveData.create(new BufferedInputStream(fin));
    AL10.alBufferData(buffer, waveFile.format, waveFile.data, waveFile.samplerate);
    // TODO FIX ERROR

    error = AL10.alGetError();
    if (error != AL10.AL_NO_ERROR) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + Maths.getALErrorString(error));
    }

    waveFile.dispose();
}

public int getBuff() {
    return buffer;
}

public void setBuff(int buff) {
    this.buffer = buff;
}

public void destroy() {
    AL10.alDeleteBuffers(buffer);
}
```

`

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code itself. It's most likely the file path that's wrong. Try `System.out.println(f.exists());` if it says `false`, then it indeed is your file path that is wrong.